# asp.net 4.5 get route parameters from routeconfig.cs

Tags: asp.net, routes

I want to route my pages on special folders base on route parameters. for example if a route parameter is 'main' i want to open default.aspx inside of main folder. because `HttpContext.Current.Request.Path` is not accessible in start of .net 4.5 apps I don't know how to retrieve the path.

I want to  do something like this:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
routes.MapPageRoute("", "{folder}", returnUrl({folder}));
}  
public string returnUrl(string path)
{
if(path=="main")
return "~/main/default.aspx";
}
```